# arduino nothing printing to serial

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I've built an arduino sketch that attempts to do a couple of different lengths of windowing and some simple calculations (mean/variance) on the analog values from a couple of sensors. Previously I had the same code for 1 sensor working as intended but the code below has been expanded with a bunch of little for loops so that everything should run for both sensors now.

I simply can't get anything at all to print to serial - even the two serial prints i put in setup and start of loop just to debug - yet the code compiles and uploads without any errors or warnings.

I apologise for including the whole sketch, I couldn't think how to break it apart to show.

```
long int currentTime = 0;
long int stopTime[2] = {0,0};
long int shortWindowTime = 0;
int shortVal[2][40];
int reflexWindowStart = 0;
int reflexWindowTime = 0;
int reflexVal[2][500];
int mean[2] = {0,0};
unsigned int variance[2] = {0,0};
int lowVal[2] = {0,0};
int peakVal[2] = {0,0};
int lowIndex[2] = {0,0};
int peakIndex[2] = {0,0};
int stopIndex[2] = {0,0};
boolean stopped[2] = {false,false};

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("wtf?");
  for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<40;j++){
      shortVal[i][j] = 0;
    }
    for(int j=0;j<500;j++){
      reflexVal[i][j] = 1023;
    }
  }

}

void loop() {

  Serial.println("wtf?");

  currentTime = micros();

  if(currentTime - shortWindowTime > 500){

    shortWindowTime = currentTime;

    writeShortWindow();

    meanVariance();

    if(reflexWindowStart == 0){
      reflexWindow();
    }
    reflexWindowStart++;
    if(reflexWindowStart > 9){
      reflexWindowStart = 0;
    } 
  }
} 

void writeShortWindow(){
  for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    for(int j=39; j>0; j--){
      shortVal[i][j] = shortVal[i][j-1];
    }
    int ground = analogRead(A5);
    shortVal[0][0] = analogRead(A1);
    analogRead(A5);
    shortVal[i][0] = analogRead(A2);
  }
}

void meanVariance(){
  for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    for(int j=0; j<39; j++){
      mean[i] = mean[i] + shortVal[i][j];
    }    
    mean[i] = mean[i] / 40;
    for(int j=0; j<39; j++){
      variance[i] = variance[i] + sq(mean[i] - shortVal[i][j]) ;
    }
    variance[i] = variance[i] / 40;
  }
}


void reflexWindow(){

    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
      if(stopped[i] == true){
        if((millis() - stopTime[i] > 20) && (peakVal[i] - shortVal[i][0] > 20) && (variance[i] <= 1)){ 
          stopped[i] = false;
          stopIndex[i] = 0;
          Serial.println("................................NOTstopped");
        }
      }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    if(stopped[i] == false){

      lowVal[i] = 1023;
      peakVal[i] = 0; 

      for(int j=stopIndex[i]; j>0; j--){
        reflexVal[i][j] = reflexVal[i][j-1];
          if(reflexVal[i][j] < lowVal[i]){
            lowVal[i] = reflexVal[i][j];
            lowIndex[i] = j;
          }
      }

      reflexVal[i][0] = shortVal[i][0];



      for(int j=lowIndex[i]; j>=0; j--){
        if(reflexVal[i][j] > peakVal[i]){
          peakVal[i] = reflexVal[i][j];
        }
      }
    }
  }


  for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    if(stopped[i] == false){
      if(peakVal[i] - lowVal[i] >= 50){
        Serial.print(i);
        Serial.println("...................................stopped");
        stopTime[i] = millis();
        stopped[i] = true;
      }
    }
  }

  for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    if(stopIndex[i] < 499){
      stopIndex[i]++;
    }
  }

  Serial.print(shortVal[0][0]);
  Serial.print(" ... ");
  Serial.print(lowVal[0]);
  Serial.print(" ... ");
  Serial.print(peakVal[0]); 
  Serial.print(" ........ ");
  Serial.print(shortVal[1][0]);
  Serial.print(" ... ");
  Serial.print(lowVal[1]);
  Serial.print(" ... ");
  Serial.println(peakVal[1]);   
}
```

Comment: Have you tried resetting the Arduino? I seem to remember I had a similar problem... The serial console sometimes becomes disconnected, but it doesn't warn you... Try re-uploading your program to the board leaving the cable connected. (I assume you are connected using USB?) I think this is what I did with mine.

Comment: I've tried uploading a number of times via usb and when I run any other sketch that I know works already it prints and runs just fine. cheers though

Comment: Just a hunch, but you could try moving (some of) your code out of setup? I'm not an expert, but I have a hunch that setup is just that, it can only initialize data in memory. If you put the serial reads and writes in loop() does it make a difference? I'm thinking on the lines of r/w to serial in setup causes problems. This might be nonsense what I'm talking though. (I think we had a problem with an fpga at uni and this sort of thing was the solution)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Leonardo board you will most likely not see the Serial.print in the setup  function.
Try changing your setup to this (notice the extra while loop waiting for the Serial)

```
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);
  Serial.println("wtf?");
  for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<40;j++){
      shortVal[i][j] = 0;
    }
    for(int j=0;j<500;j++){
      reflexVal[i][j] = 1023;
    }
  }
}
```

The reason behind this you can read in the Arduino docs for Leonardo http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoLeonardo#toc3 but in short is that Leonardo doesnt resets the serial port when opening the serial stream.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but I'm actually on an Uno and anyway this still wouldn't explain why the serial print at the start of the loop doesn't run.

Comment: then Im guessing you are running out of memory which is causing this very hard to debug errors since no errors is shown in compile. Try to add up the ammount of bytes all your variables in the top is using and see if this is the case. Some more info on memory can be found here http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Memory

Comment: I did a quick look and just this line "int reflexVal[2][500];" is adding 2000 bytes to the SRAM of which Arduino Uno has a total of 2048. So I think for sure some of your problems is memory related.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked your BAUD rate in serial monitor, because if it is different, it will not show anything.
be sure the one in serial monitor and in `Serial.begin(<BAUD rate here>)` is the same